# assertEqual - two identical lists, why I get strange result?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have unit tests:

```
import unittest

class TestFail(unittest.TestCase):
    def testFail(self):
        data = range(5)
        self.assertEqual(data, insertion_sorting(data))

class TestSuccess(unittest.TestCase):   
    def testSuccess(self):
        data = range(5)
        self.assertEqual([0,1,2,3,4], insertion_sorting(data))


def insertion_sorting(data):
        result = []
        while len(data):
            min_index = 0
            for i in range(len(data)):
                if data[i] < data[min_index]: min_index = i
            result.append(data[min_index])
            del data[min_index] 
        return result 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

TestSuccess ran successful, but TestFail raises:

> AssertionError: Lists differ: [] != [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>
> Second list contains 5 additional elements. First extra element 0: 0
>
> - []
> - [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

**Could you explain me, why TestSuccess ran successful, but TestFail not?**

Answer (score 2):

Your `insertion_sorting()` function is *destructive*: it modifies in-place the list you pass. Therefore, the list referenced by the `data` variable defined in `TestFail()` will indeed be cleared during the call to `insertion_sorting()`.

A simple workaround would be to operate on a copy of the list:

```
self.assertEqual(data, insertion_sorting(data[:]))
```

A more complicated option would be to refactor `insertion_sorting()` so it is not destructive.

Comment: `s/data/the list referenced by the two distinct variables both called data/g`

Comment: @delnan, yup, this can be confusing. I tried to be more specific.

Comment: You're still mixing up the variable (or "name") and the list (which is references from several places, including two distinct variables/names). Given that aliasing is the entire problem here, I'd say that's a rather important distinction to make.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
data = range(5)
print data
print insertion_sorting(data)
print data
```

Do you see what happens? You delete the contents of `data`.

And to answer your real question - `TestFail` failed because `data` is empty after the sorting, while in `TestSuccess` you check against a different list.